# How get rerouted link of a web url

Tags: java, redirect, http-redirect

I have a link

```
String url = "original_internet_url";
```

if I visit that link then the browser will redirect to `another_url`. 
My question is how to use Java, or Spring to get the redirected `another_url` programmatically.

Update: I want to get the redirected url, not "how to redirect url with Spring". For example: If you visit `https://www.fb.com/` then you will be redirected to `https://www.facebook.com/`. Given `https://www.fb.com/`, how to know that the final url is `https://www.facebook.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two ways.

First:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", projectUrl);
}
```

Second:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method() {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + projectUrl);

    }
```

Comment: Update: I want to get the redirected url, not "how to redirect url with Spring". For example: If you visit `https://www.fb.com/` then you will be redirected to `https://www.facebook.com/`. Given `https://www.fb.com/`, how to know that the final url is `https://www.facebook.com/`. Your answer is for another question.

Comment: Did you check the below link? https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Comment: Your answer is out of context. I appreciate your help but you don't understand the question yet.